# Activity Intent not launched

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application the main activity is launched but on button click the second activity is not launched via intent.

This is my log cat entry

```
08-21 23:29:35.568: D/dalvikvm(680): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 53% free 2544K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 272ms
08-21 23:29:36.319: D/TimesheetMgmt Log(680): -->Main activity launched. 
08-21 23:29:53.908: D/TimesheetMgmt Log(680): -->New Task button clicked. 
08-21 23:29:54.128: D/AndroidRuntime(680): Shutting down VM
08-21 23:29:54.128: W/dalvikvm(680): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.timesheetmgmt/com.timesheetmgmt.NewTaskActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.timesheetmgmt.NewTaskActivity.<init>(NewTaskActivity.java:16)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
08-21 23:29:54.198: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  ... 11 more
08-21 23:29:58.879: I/Process(680): Sending signal. PID: 680 SIG: 9
```

Main Activity code:

```
 package com.timesheetmgmt;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private static final String DEBUG_TAG= "TimesheetMgmt Log";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "-->Main activity launched. ");
    Button btnNewTask=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewTask);
    btnNewTask.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnNewTask){
        try {
             Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "-->New Task button clicked. ");
             Intent in=new Intent(this,NewTaskActivity.class);
             in.putExtra("str", "jjalj new task activity");
             startActivity(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


 }
```

in log cat file i can see main activity launched and when i click the new task button the error as mentioned above in log cat and force close button comes on emulator.

Comment: you have a null pointer  @ com.timesheetmgmt.NewTaskActivity.(NewTaskActivity.java:16

Comment: Can you add your code please? Also, did you add the new `Activity` to your manifest?

Comment: It seems you want to use a view via findViewById, which doesn't exist or not inflated yet.

Comment: ya i added my new activity to manifest file.

Comment: Still couldn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is `NewActivity` at line 16. That is your problem. You are getting a `NullPointerException` at that location.

Answer (score 0):

As the log says you have a problem in findViewById in NewTaskActivity.
Maybe you are looking for a View that doesn't exist and you are making some operations on it causing NullPointerException.

Be sure that in you NewTaskActivity you are inflating the right layout and check if the view with the id you're using exist in that layout.